# Grep function returning nothing from lists

Tags: r, list, twitter

I am trying to use the grep() function in R to analyze data from tweets, but when I try to search keywords that I know exist in the tweets, grep() is returning "integer(0)".

So I am creating lists using the searchTwitter() function:

```
NC.monday <- searchTwitter("UNC", n = 5000, since = "2015-11-30", until = "2015-12-01")
NC.monday <- unlist(NC.monday)
```

So I have a list of 5000 tweets that all contain "UNC" stored in an object called NC.monday. Here is one example tweet from the list of 5000, index 4977:

```
[[4977]]
[1] "User1: RT @ESPNAndyKatz: UNC's Marcus Paige will play against Maryland in ACC-Big Ten Challenge https://t.co/devMeNiHct"
```

I can see when I look through the tweets that some tweets contain the word "Paige", for example, but when I search for them using the grep() function it is returning "integer(0)"

```
>grep("Paige", NC.monday)
integer(0)
```

I know that the word "Paige" is located in some of those tweets, so why isn't grep() showing me where they are?

Comment: We would need to see an example of `NC.monday`

Comment: @RichardScriven I've added an example, hope that helps

Comment: Are you sure you executed `NC.monday <- unlist(NC.monday)` Your example data looks like a list and grep needs a character vector. But we can't check without a `dput(head(NC.monday))`

Answer (score 0):

try this to convert the list of tweets to a data frame, and filter the  column of data frame named "text" which contains the tweet:

```
NC.monday.df <- twitteR::twListToDF(NC.monday)
NC.monday.df.filtered <- NC.monday.df[grepl("Paige", NC.monday.df$text, ignore.case=TRUE),]
```

and look up how R performs indexing.